# How does facebook update the feeds dynamically?

Tags: facebook

How does facebook update the feeds automatically without even refreshing the page , moreover the feeds get added up on the top of the page.
Which language tho they use to make that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uses PHP as it's server side scripting language. This is combined with JavaScript for updating the browser without refreshing the page, using AJAX techniques.

A JavaScript function 'silently' requests a new page (containing refreshed feed data etc), and then updates the document's elements accordingly.

Comment: So basically now i'd need to learn ajax and javascript to do something like that.

Comment: @alfie I do understand javascript and php and ajax techniques, what i want to understand is how effectively they are managing wat post to show in scrolling news feed as news feed is totally dynamic and not a static list of posts which can be marked with number 1 to n and retrieve consistently for letsay next 10-12 posts.